# PHP, Microsoft IIS: how can I increate upload limit?

Tags: php, iis

I need to incrase the php file upload limit of 8MB on an IIS server.

I don't have access to configuration files, so I was wondering how to increase it (I need something similar to .htaccess for apache..

thanks

Comment: Mmm, IIRC it was possible to have local `php.ini` s in IIS (provided they are allowed, which they may not be), but I can't find any details right now. Can't you talk to your hosting provider?

Comment: well, the point is that users can upload videos bigger than 8M on a Joomla installation on the same server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP configuration `upload_max_filesize` is what you want to change.

Unfortunately it can only be changed from php.ini.  If you don't have access to php.ini, you're out of luck (on IIS).